# Heroku free SSL for paid dynos not working on "old" app

Tags: django, ssl, heroku

I have a django app created before the announcement of free SSL Dynos on Heroku.

I followed throught the tutorial [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management)

```
> heroku certs:auto:enable

Enabling Automatic Certificate Management... done

=== Your certificate will now be managed by Heroku.  Check the status by running 

> heroku certs:auto

=== Automatic Certificate Management is enabled on codetiger


  Domain            Status
 ────────────────  ─────── 
  www.site.com  Failing 
  site.com      Failing

=== Some domains are failing validation, please verify that your DNS matches: heroku domains
```

When I run the `heroku domains` command, it shows me the following

```
=== codetiger Heroku Domain
codetiger.herokuapp.com

=== codetiger Custom Domains
Domain Name       DNS Target
────────────────  ──────────────────────────────
www.site.com  www.site.com.herokudns.com
site.com      site.com.herokudns.com
```

And the

```
Type    Hostname      Value                      TTL (seconds)  
CNAME   www.site.com  www.site.com.herokudns.com 43200
CNAME   *.site.com site.com.herokudns.com.       1800
```

Even after doing all that, when I run `heroku certs:info` I only see
`site has no SSL certificates`

What can I do for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a test, can you remove the wildcard CNAME? Seems like Heroku [does not support that](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#known-limitations) currently.

> ACM does not support applications that have wildcard custom domains.

Any other flags in those Known Limitations that might help?